# UIBarButtonItem(customView:) -- not tappable

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have the following in `viewDidLoad`. It sets a custom `rightBarButtonItem` (in a custom `UINavigationBar`).

```
    let button = UIButton()
    let attrs = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Montserrat-Light", size: 14)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black]
    let title = NSAttributedString(string: "Sign In", attributes: attrs)
    button.setAttributedTitle(title, for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.pushVcLogin), for: .touchUpInside)

    let parentView = UIView(frame: button.bounds)
    parentView.addSubview(button)
    button.sizeToFit()
    parentView.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: button.bounds.size.width, height: button.bounds.size.height)

    self.navItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: parentView)
```

The custom `UIBarButtonItem` looks the way it should, but it's not tappable.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you share the code of "pushVcLogin"?

Comment: What do you mean by "custom `UINavigationBar`"? Are you using `UINavigationController` or not? Is just the visual appearance that is "custom", or are you using a stand-alone navigation bar?

Comment: Sorry y'all, I figured it out -- this whole view controller is (cue @NicolasMiari's question) nested in a UINavigationController, and that controller was (invisibly) superimposed its UINavigationBar over my whole view including my custom UINavigationBar.

Answer (score 1):

First of all if your view hierarchy has UINavigationController

Secondly you can use the navigationItem and add the custom UIBarButtonItem on it.

I just checked with the following code and it works.

```
    let button = UIButton()        
    let attrs = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Montserrat-Light", size: 14)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black]
    let title = NSAttributedString(string: "Sign In", attributes: attrs)
    button.setAttributedTitle(title, for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.pushVcLogin), for: .touchUpInside)

    let parentView = UIView(frame: button.bounds)
    parentView.addSubview(button)
    button.sizeToFit()
    parentView.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: button.bounds.size.width, height: button.bounds.size.height)

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: parentView)
```

also here is the storyboard image how the navigationController and viewController looks like.

[image]